# How to type convert a slice of type aliases

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type alias int
type aliases []*alias

func main() {
    a1 := alias(1)
    t := aliases{&a1}

    fmt.Println([]*int([]*alias(t)))
}
```

The type `type aliases []*alias` is essentially `[]*int`

I want to be able to type convert `aliases` back to `[]*int`

Answer (score 2):

You can with unsafe.Pointer, a little bit unsafe so not recommended

```
PointerToSliceOfPointersToInt := (*([]*int))(unsafe.Pointer(&t))
```

try it works https://play.golang.org/p/6AWd1W_it3

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you could do that by doing right casting.

```
type alias int
type aliases []*alias

func main() {
    a1 := alias(1)
    t := aliases{&a1}

    orig := int(*([]*alias(t)[0]))
    fmt.Println(orig)
}
```

Example on  http://play.golang.org/p/1WosCIUZSa

If you want to get all values (not just the first index) you have to loop and cast each element.

```
func main() {
    a1 := alias(1)
    t := aliases{&a1}

    orig := []*int{}

    for _, each := range t {
        temp := int(*each)
        orig = append(orig, &temp)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", orig) // []*int{(*int)(0x10434114)}
}
```

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/Sx4JK3kA45